# What is electric field?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

What is electric field in real? Any theory?

We generally think it as a mathematical construct but it's a real quantity. So what is the nature of that quantity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are Electromagnetic field real physical entity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/536169/)

Comment: 'We generally think it as a mathematical construct but it's a real quantity.' It would help if it was made explicit who thinks this. Also, what motivates you to consider it as a 'real quantity'?

Answer (score 2):

It is a elementary field of nature. We can describe it as a component of the electromagnetic field that includes also the magnetic field. Under the current experimental evidence, we cannot explain the electromagnetic field in terms of anything more fundamental.

Comment: This could be satisfying but unanswering because I am talking about if there is something travelling in real then what is it?

Comment: @PredakingAskboss if you modify an electric field (let’s say by moving charges around), then you create ripples in this field, we usually call them electromagnetic waves. These waves update the field at the speed of light. These waves need no medium, EM waves can travel in a vacuum.

Answer (score 1):

An electric field is the "reach" of an electric charge.

Why fields exist, we can't explain. We can only measure *that* they exist and investigate *how* they work.

It may seem puzzling and maybe unimaginable and unintuitive. But it's not much different from, say, the very well-know gravitational field (except for the sign - gravity can only attract not repel, but that's besides the point):

You fall down towards Earth due to gravity. If you go to the other side of Earth, then you are still pulled towards the centre of Earth. The higher up you come, the weaker gravity is. This means that at every point around the Earth, there is a certain gravitational pull in you, in your mass. To standardize it you might ask how large this pull is per unit mass, so: *gravitational force per kilogram*.

**This** is a field. A gravitational field in this case. It extends into empty space and travels through no medium. We define it on a per-unit base to keep it standardized. An electric field is exactly the same, just caused by another source: whereas gravitational fields spring from mass, electric fields spring from electric charges. An electric field is thus: **electric force per unit charge** at any given point.

It is hard to explain *why* these masses and charges cause fields around them. Physics is rarely able to explain "why" questions at the fundamental level. Nevertheless, if you intuitively accept the explanation of gravity, then it should be no issue to likewise accept electric fields.

Comment: Nice explanation. But can you answer what is that field? Is it an energy Or something else?

Comment: @PredakingAskboss Well, what is the gravitational field? Is it energy? I would say no. A field is defined as **force per unit**. So a field is rather *force* than energy, so to say.