# Is electromagnetism simply a model?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

Electrons have an e-field, and a moving e-field causes a b-field. These fields are defined in such a way that it makes calculating things like forces much simpler.

Is this just a model and there aren't actual 'waves' traversing around us, but rather mere forces caused by a movement of an electron? If the force caused by a charge wasn't viewed as a wave, would electromagnetism only be a model for calculating the effects of the charge, utilizing waves as a tool?

If so, is it fine to propose that visible light is simply our brain's reaction to certain forces caused by moving electrons in a certain frequency?

Comment: The idea that electrons exist is itself a model.

Comment: Modern science doesn't attempt to say "what's actually happening". Instead, we construct theories that model some part of reality to some degree of accuracy. Then we work out the implications of the theory, and see how well they match up with our observations.

Comment: Everything is a model really. Because you have only your senses through which to interpret things and that interpretation occurs in a representation inside your brain. Who knows what's *really* on the outside? This is kind of like the philosophy of The Matrix.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the electromagnetic field a real physical entity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/536169/is-the-electromagnetic-field-a-real-physical-entity)

Answer (score 9):

Everything is a model. If you walk outside and feel the sun on your face, you can either say that your skin is absorbing electromagnetic radiation or that it is experiencing a non-local interaction with charged particles 100 million miles away and about eight minutes in the past.

> Is this just a model and there aren't actual 'waves' traversing around us, but rather mere forces caused by a movement of an electron?

I don't know what you mean by this. If you predict the result of some experiment by modeling electromagnetism using fields and waves, then your predictions will come true. That doesn't mean that you can't bend over backwards (philosophically and mathematically) to come up with an alternative picture that doesn't involve waves, but there is exactly zero reason to do so unless we discovered that the Maxwell equations did not match with experiments (they do).

> If so, is it fine to propose that visible light is simply our brain's reaction to certain forces caused by moving electrons in a certain frequency?

You can propose whatever you want, but in order for that to be true those forces would have to be nonlocal in both space and time - i.e. the force you experience now depends on where other particles were and what they were doing last Tuesday. If that's unappealing to you, as it is to most people, then you're stuck with fields.